# Flexbox with white-space: pre

Tags: html, css, flexbox, whitespace

I have a flexbox container that uses `white-space: pre` formatting and contains some whitespace-only text nodes. However unless the whitespaces are wrapped in a `span` these are not displayed. Why is this happening and could I make it work without using the extra spans?

(btw. I am using flexbox to make some other elements grow to full width of the container)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  white-space: pre;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<span>    </span><span class="red">foo</span><span>    </span><span class="blue">bar</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <span class="red">foo</span>    <span class="blue">bar</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6zrm81tk/1/

Comment: Why don't you use `&nbsp;` for spaces in between `span` tags?

Comment: Hmm, I could do that - it's questionable though whether it is any better than wrapping the spaces inside span element. But TBH in reality I use pre-wrap (doesn't matter in this example) and if a line happens to be too long I'd prefer to wrap it.
The application is actually emulating a terminal, reading input/output over websocket and then using ansi_up to convert ANSI sequences into HTML.